# Search input field like TripAdvisor functionality

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a similar search form like tripadvisors (at least UI and Front Design speaking) but i have till now a few issues.
On the first photo is how is my search bar with the class name for testing purposes "asdf".
[image]

so in the second picture we have the issue, the expandable part of the form being a bit wider than the input search field.
[image]

In the third pict if with have the issue if i try to assign the same width of the rest of the form with the input["text"] field of the search form.

[image]

Below my basic html and css code.

HTML

```
     <div class="aboutUs">

            <div class="textFlexContainer">

             <div class="text-box">
                <h1 class="heading-primary">
                    <span class="heading-primary-main">City</span>   
                    <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where summer happens</span>   

                </h1>
              
                
                <form class="search-box" action="/search">
                  <input class="asdf" type="search" placeholder="Explore City">
                  
                    
                  <div class="search-page">
              
                    <h3>Explore City</h3>
                
              
                      <ul class="search-menu-list">
                
                      <li><a href="#">Our Daily Suggestions</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">City Tours</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Restaurants</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Things to do</a></li>
                  
                    </ul>
                
              
                <h3>Recently Reviewed</h3>

              </div>
              </form>
            </div>

                  

                </div> 
                
              </div>
```

And CSS

```
    .search-box{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:15;
  padding:2rem;
  
  
}

.asdf {
  
  width: 80%;
  padding:2rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom:2px solid white;
  margin-top:2.5rem;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: green;
  
 
  color: #fff;
  
}


h3{
  color:#fff;
  margin-top:2rem;
}

.search-page {


  height: fit-content;
  background-color:green;

 
  
 
  text-align: center;
  padding:4rem 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
 
  display: none;
 
  
}

.search-page.visible {
  display: block;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  
  
}


.search-page .search-menu-list{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 

}

.search-page  .search-menu-list li{
  list-style: none;
}

.search-page .search-menu-list li a:hover{
  transform: translateY(-1rem);

}

.search-page  .search-menu-list li a{
  display: inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 11px 13px 11px 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  
}

.aboutUs{


  display: grid;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right  bottom, rgba(53, 170, 120, 0.8), rgba(20, 139, 102, 0.8)) ,url(../img/ch4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  grid-column-start: 1; 
  grid-column-end: 13; 
  grid-row-start: 2; 
  grid-row-end: 3; 
 
  
}


.textFlexContainer{
  
    display:flex;
    align-self: center;
    
    
}

.heading-primary {
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main{

display: block;
font-size: 6rem;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 3.5rem;

}

.heading-primary-sub {

  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1.8rem;

}

.text-box {
 
  display: inline-block;

  /* This content should just be in the normal flow of the page */
  /*
    position: absolute
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50% ,-50%);
  */
  text-align: center;
  /*  Because we're using flexbox, we can center the content both horizontally and vertically
   *  using this declaration
   */
  margin: auto;
  
  
  
 
}



Additionaly i would love if when i click on the search bar field and the form is expanding to not have the letters above the search bar to getting squeezed on the top.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you need here but here's a fix for image 3. Adding 2 lines of code to your .search-page fixes the alignment issue.

```
    .search-page{
  height: fit-content;
  background-color:green;
  width:80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding:4rem 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  display: all;
}
```

The width sets it to line up with the size of the text input of the form. The margin: 0 auto; is a good way to quickly center elements in css.

Comment: `all` does not seem to be a valid value for `display`, but I think you meant to include the `margin: auto` you described instead.

Comment: i did that on the third picture and although they have the same width the position gets a bit messy...
I am thinking even to reconstruct that part of my webpage but i want to do it exactly as Tripadvisor search expandable form.

Comment: Edit: Actually by setting these two lines it made it work so its pretty much on the size that i want and well aligned! thank you so much! it drove me mad for 2-3 days! Though the issue of the headline squeezing on the top when i expand the bar is still remain...
Picture 2. The white space between the top of C I T Y and green navbar should remain always the same

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the expandable part when I tested your code but have you tried changing the width to become small and then do a margin-left to move de expandable part and align it with the search?

Comment: ah yes there is the need for a JS script when you click on the input field of search bar.
I tried to change the width of the expandable part and so it becomes small and the same width with the search field (as you can see in the picture 3) but when i am trying to use margin-left to align it its not web responsive when i change the size of my browser it collapses and mess eventually